# GWT + GXT Generate did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Need to generate classes dynamically using GWT + GXT, I am taking the following error in code generator:

Line 12: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 15: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 15: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorContext; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 15: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators are not "client code", they should be outside your "client path": outside your `client` subpackage if using the defaults / naming convention (generally rather into a `rebind` subpackage).